# Why am I getting Error 403: org_internal error in gmail authentication?

Tags: python-3.x, google-api

Currently, now I have been working to develop an app in which we have done code for Gmail integration. We are importing all Gmail emails into our database.

Our domain is like `mytest` and currently, I am testing with mayank@mytest.com which is a Gmail account.

So I am able to integrate `mayank@test.com` successfully and able to import all 50 mails into the database also.

But when I am trying with `mayankprajapati21@gmail.com` which is my other id, I am getting error like below.

```
Authorization Error
Error 403: org_internal
This client is restricted to users within its organization.
```

I am searching to find a solution for a day but not able to find it.

If any have past experience with Google API, pls let me know how to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: The client has been set up for use with Gsuite users not normal gmail users.

Comment: & How can we set it for norma gmail users also.?

Comment: Probably need to remove the domain restriction https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/restricting-domains